# In VBA what is the correct syntax to set a range of cells in one sheet to the values of a range in another sheet using variables?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to build s valid VBA command that uses variables.
Here's a hard coded example that does work:
'    `temp.Range("A1:P1").Value2 = pollResults.Range("A1:P1").Value2`

Here's my attempt at the same command with variables substituted for rows and last columns:

```
temp.Range(Chr(34) & "A" & lastTempRow & ":" & lastColumn & lastTempRow & Chr(34)).Value2 _
= pollResults.Range(Chr(34) & "A" & RowCount & ":" & lastColumn & RowCount & Chr(34)).Value2
```

The above gives me runtime error '1004'. Method 'Range of object' _Worksheet' failed.

I've looked at other answers on Ranges but none seem to fit my requirements.

Comment: Execute `? Chr(34) & "A" & lastTempRow & ":" & lastColumn & lastTempRow & Chr(34)` and observe the output. Compare it to `? "A1:P1"`.

Comment: If you're building a string for a range, could you do something like: `dataRange = "A" & CStr(lastTempRow) & ":" & CStr(lastColumn) & CStr(lastTempRow)`. Then just reference it as `Range(dataRange)` ? Not sure what variable types you have, but I don't think you need the double quotes there.

Comment: @GSerg it's looks identical to the "A1:P1" with only the last column value being "L" instead of "P". It shows as type Variant in the watch window

Comment: @Sudio - your idea provided the answer. I just removed the CHR(34) for all parts of the original command and it worked the way I intended.

Comment: @Elliot The first one gives `"A1:P1"`, the second `A1:P1`.